# meteor: product grid with pictures in FS collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to make a grid of a 'partner' collection
Each partner consist of a `partnerGridForm` template

```
<template name="partnerGridForm">
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        {{_id}}

        {{#each profileImages}}
            {{>partnerGridImage}}
        {{/each}}

        <h3 class="panel-title">{{profile.partner_company}}</h3>
        <hr>


        {{profile.partner_address_line_1}}<br>
        {{#if profile.partner_address_line2}}
            {{profile.partner_address_line2}}<br>
        {{/if}}
        {{profile.partner_zipcode}} {{profile.partner_city}}<br>
        {{profile.partner_state}} - {{profile.partner_country}}<br>
        {{profile.partner_phone_nr}}<br>
        {{profile.partner_mobile_nr}}<br>
        <hr>
        <b>
        {{profile.partner_category}}<br>
        {{profile.partner_sub_category}}</b>
        <hr>
        {{{profile.partner_promo_text}}}


    </div><!-- end panel -->
</div><!-- end feature -->
</template>
```

All these partnerGridForm templates are displayed on a page trough a loop trough the partner collection (which is in fact the user collection)

```
<template name="partnerGrid">
    <div class="container container-top">
     {{#each partners}}
        {{>partnerGridForm}}
     {{/each}}
    </div> <!-- end container -->
</template>
```

The pictures for each partner are stored separately in a `ProductImages.fs` file

I want each `partnerGridForm` to display the images in the partnerGridForm but I can't make it work.

Trough the Reactive character of meteor all my gridforms are constantly updated with the last picture I get.

Currently i have the following helpers on the partnerGrid template

```
  // Template Helpers
Template.partnerGrid.helpers({
    partners: function () {
        return Meteor.users.find();
    },
});


// On rendering get lists
Template.partnerGrid.onRendered(function (event,template) {

    if (typeof  partnerSub !== 'undefined') {
        if ( partnerSub != null ) {
            partnerSub.stop();
        };
    };
    partnerSub = Meteor.subscribe('partnerList');

});
```

and the following helpers on the partnerGridForm template

```
Template.partnerGridForm.helpers({
    profileImages: function() {
        return PartnerImages.find();
    },

});

Template.partnerGridForm.onRendered(function(event,template){
    currentPartner = Template.currentData()    // Get current data in template
    currentPartnerId = currentPartner._id;
    if (typeof  ImageSub !== 'undefined') {
        if ( ImageSub != null ) {
            ImageSub.stop();
        };
    };
    ImageSub = Meteor.subscribe('partnerImages', currentPartnerId);
});
```

The problem is that the helpers on the partnerGridForm update each form that is rendered so each form wil always get the last image?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what problem you're having? Is it that you do not want the pictures to update? Or is it that you don't know how to make a helper to show the picture? It might help to see your `partnerGridImage` helper(s).

Comment: I have added the helper code to the question ! Best regards